# Why including bom doesn't work?

Tags: maven, maven-bom

I found something doesn't work that I expected to work.

I imported the `org.glassfish.jersey:jersey-bom` in my `dependencyManagement` section.

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
       <version>2.26-b03</version>
       <type>pom</type>
       <scope>include</scope>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

That [pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/jersey-bom/2.26-b03/jersey-bom-2.26-b03.pom) clearly includes following dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I add my own dependency

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And `mvn` complains.

> 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar is missing. @ line 33, column 17

What's wrong with my pom?

Comment: You should use `import` instead of `include` for `<scope>...</scope>`....

Comment: @khmarbaise That's it mate! Thanks!

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6213

Answer (score 0):

Did you define `project-version` as a property? I guess not, since you're not using it to specify the version of your BOM.

Using the literal string, this should work:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What intrigues me is that you shouldn't need to specify `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.26-b03` in `<dependencyManagement>` since it is part of the BOM, but the dependency doesn't work if it is not there.